# FatWire Content Server CSDT import/export failure

Tags: java, fatwire

I am trying to import and export workspace from/to Fatwire ContentServer using CSDT.

I first wanted to try a "simple" export of the provided "FirstSiteII" site with the following command :

```
java -classpath $CSDTJAR_FOLDER/csdt-client-1.0.4.jar:$CSDTJAR_FOLDER/lib/* com.fatwire.csdt.client.main.CSDT $CS_URL username=fwadmin password=myPassword cmd=export datastore=test fromSites=FirstSiteII 'resources=@ALL_ASSETS:*'
```

But, I got this error :

```
     *** Exporting batch 1398411569399
Exporting ASSETDATA Document_CD:1112649867903 (batch 1398411569399)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil._getSerializer(y:930)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil._export(y:158)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil.Export(y:575)
    at com.fatwire.csdt.service.impl.ExportService._export(y:3405)
    at com.fatwire.csdt.service.impl.ExportService.execute(y:2237)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cs_005fdeployed.OpenMarket.Xcelerate.PrologActions.Publish.csdt.CSDTService_jsp._jspService(CSDTService_jsp.java:170)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.ServletRequest.include(y:3531)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.K.H(y:2027)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.H.A(y:2278)
    at COM.FutureTense.Platform.NONE.D.A(y:2409)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.H.A(y:1535)
    at COM.FutureTense.Platform.NONE.D$_D.run(y:338)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.jspExecute(y:2452)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.evalTemplate(y:218)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.A(y:3467)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.evalPage(y:3048)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.execute(y:2757)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.FTServlet.execute(y:1088)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.FTServlet.doPost(y:3299)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.ContextHeaderFilter.doFilterWork(y:526)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.RunOncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(y:2152)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(y:1020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

 Error while exporting: Export Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializer
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializer
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil._export(y:3146)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil.Export(y:575)
    at com.fatwire.csdt.service.impl.ExportService._export(y:3405)
    at com.fatwire.csdt.service.impl.ExportService.execute(y:2237)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.cs_005fdeployed.OpenMarket.Xcelerate.PrologActions.Publish.csdt.CSDTService_jsp._jspService(CSDTService_jsp.java:170)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.ServletRequest.include(y:3531)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.K.H(y:2027)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.H.A(y:2278)
    at COM.FutureTense.Platform.NONE.D.A(y:2409)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.H.A(y:1535)
    at COM.FutureTense.Platform.NONE.D$_D.run(y:338)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.jspExecute(y:2452)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.evalTemplate(y:218)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.A(y:3467)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.evalPage(y:3048)
    at COM.FutureTense.Common.j.execute(y:2757)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.FTServlet.execute(y:1088)
    at COM.FutureTense.Servlet.FTServlet.doPost(y:3299)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.ContextHeaderFilter.doFilterWork(y:526)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.RunOncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(y:2152)
    at com.fatwire.cs.core.logging.context.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(y:1020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil._getSerializer(y:930)
    at com.fatwire.realtime.packager.CSDTUtil._export(y:158)
    ... 47 more


Export Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializerOutput saved to /usr/share/tomcat6/fatwire/export/envision/test
```

Meanwhile, the `cmd=listcs` works as expected...

Any ideas where I can find this `com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializerOutput`, because, indeed, none of the jar in the classpth contains this class ?

I am using Fatwire ContentServer 7.6.2 patch 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake : it does not work because I did not installed CAS.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.fatwire.rest.util.AssetJAXBSerializer` class is in `rest-api-local-impl-1.1.4.jar`, which should be in your Tomcat `webapps/cs/WEB-INF/lib` folder. You shouldn't need to specify this in the classpath when running CSDT, though - Fatwire will be using it to generate the XML for your asset exports.